# Expanding FLOT graph on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, flot

I'm using **flot** library to plot some data. Flot uses height and width property of that div to draw the data plot like so

```
<div id="graph" style="width: 300px; height: 300px;"></div>
```

I would like to make this graph(div) clickable which expands to a bigger size say 500*500. Which means the width and height of the plot should be 500*500 but should be first visible in 300*300. Upon clicking, it should expand and reveal its original size. I guess setting initial height and width is required for flot to work. How can I achieve this ?

Techniques that I've tried :
1) Using jquery toggle which takes the parent class and animates its height and width like this

```
$(this).parent().animate({'height': '500px'},{'width': '500px'});
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use your code to expand the graph but you also have to redraw it with the new size.
With this code you can redraw the graph after the expanding has finished:

```
$('#graph').on('click', function () {
    $(this).animate({
        'height': '600px',
        'width': '600px'
    }, function () {
        plot.resize();
        plot.setupGrid();
        plot.draw();
    });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

for animation try like this:

```
$('#graph').animate({'height': '500px','width': '500px'});
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6fvdJ/3/)

for click + animation:

```
$('#graph').on('click', function(){
   $(this).animate({'height': '500px','width': '500px'});
})
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6fvdJ/4/)